# Android Studio syncing error when changing project SDK to android pie

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting this error when my project syncs:

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\Noahd\AndroidStudioProjects\randomizer\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\Noahd\AndroidStudioProjects\randomizer\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\Noahd\AndroidStudioProjects\randomizer\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1087: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
C:\Users\Noahd\AndroidStudioProjects\randomizer\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1088: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\Noahd\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\0eca6d6c39cae440624a131cc96c7f87\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Noahd\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\Noahd\AndroidStudioProjects\randomizer\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\Noahd\AndroidStudioProjects\randomizer\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\Noahd\AndroidStudioProjects\randomizer\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\Noahd\AndroidStudioProjects\randomizer\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        pro.bwac.randomizer\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\Noahd\AndroidStudioProjects\randomizer\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Why could this be? My project was fine up until I found that my android phone was on Android Oreo, and my project was Android Pie so I downloaded the Oreo SDK and changed the projects min and target SDK. And that broke everything and I can't run it.

Comment: share your min, max sdk and compile sdk versions. And the support libraries version as well

Answer (score 0):

> Why could this be? My project was fine up until I found that my
>   android phone was on Android Oreo, and my project was Android Pie so I
>   downloaded the Oreo SDK and changed the projects min and target SDK.
>   And that broke everything and I can't run it.

Looks like there is a mismatch between compile sdk version and support libraries version. Assuming based on what you mentioned above, as you might have missed updating support libraries version matching compile sdk version.

Comment: How to i change the support libraries to match the sdk?

Comment: my dear, I am talking about code you have kept in app:build.gradle file

Comment: My dear I am asking about the code of app:build.gradle file

Comment: I have added it to the qestion

Comment: my dear I am asking about build.gradle of app module